# Making selected radio buttons in bold type

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

so my professor asked us to make a simple HTML Multiple Choice Quiz and I've already done making one. My problem is how to make the correct answers in BOLD type when I click the "submit" button. Is that possible? Can you help me with the script code to use?

Please bear with me my knowledge in programming is very limited your help would be really appreciated. Thank you in advance!

```
function BoldQuestions()
{
  var txt = document.getElementsByName();
  for(var i = 0; i < txt.length; i++)
  {
    if(txt[i].checked)
   {
      if(txt[i].value=="correct")
      alert("The Correct Answers Are Now In Bold Style") 
      document.write( txt + txt.bold())
      break;
   }
  }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/htzcfg8k/

Comment: kindly post a [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Rather than posting code on another site, reduce it to the minimum that displays your issue and post it here. Don't post code in comments, if you have updates to the question, edit it (and preferably highlight significant changes so it's easy for others to see what changed).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to wrap the text with an html tag, you can change its CSS with something like this:

```
if (txt[i].value == "correct") {
    txt[i].style.fontWeight = "bold";
}
```

---

If you wanted to do this the "correct" way, you would add a class to your CSS file, and then give the correct answers the CSS class.

CSS:

```
.correct {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Javascript:

```
if (txt[i].value == "correct") {

    txt[i].className += " correct";

}
```

By doing this, you can change the style of the `correct` answers however you want without having to mess with JS again.  If you were on a team, for example, someone else that didn't know JS could just edit CSS instead.

---

> can i just ask where should I write the CSS part?

You would write your CSS in a file.  You could name it something like `styles.css`.  You then link `styles.css` to your html document in the header just above where you link your script.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
```

If your professor hasn't gone over CSS, then you probably don't need to worry about adding an extra CSS file.  Just use the code at the very top of this answer if that is the case.  Good luck :)

Comment: Better to add a class and matching CSS so that editing the style doesn't require editing the script.

Comment: @RobG Fair enough.  I wasn't considering best practices since it is just a homework assignment.  I'll update the answer

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)can i just ask where should I write the CSS part?

Comment: @AlvinDelaRosa If this answer addressed your problem, then click the checkmark to mark it as the accepted answer :)

Comment: another question, So i just can use The code you provided at the very top as a replacement in the code that i used right?

Comment: @AlvinDelaRosa assuming the code before that works as intended, yes. I'm on a tablet, so making a demo would take too long.